# Running Behat tests with Appium

Tags: android, appium, selenium-grid, behat

So far I managed to start selenium grid and register appium with nodeconfig file.
Next step would be to create the profile in beta.yml to use for running with appium.

My appium nodeconfig file is:

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName":"Android",
"version":"5.1",
"maxInstances":1,
"platform":"ANDROID",
"deviceName":"emulator-5554",
"applicationName":"Nexus"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"nodeTimeout":120,
"timeout":30000,
"proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"url":"http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub",
"maxSession":1,
"port":4723,
"hub":"0.0.0.0:4444/grid/register",
"hubPort":"4444",
"hubHost":"0.0.0.0",
"register":true,
"registerCycle":10000,
"nodePolling":2000
}
}
```

Please advise how should I set capabilities in the .yml file. So far I tried:

```
appium:
  extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        base_url:url_here  
        javascript_session: 'selenium2'
        selenium2:
          browser: 'android'
          wd_host: http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
          capabilities: {"platformName": "Android", "browserName": "Browser", "applicationName":"Nexus", "deviceName": "emulator-5554"}
```

and I get error saying that capabilities don't exist.
I also tried putting the capabilities in context/parameters but still it doesn't match.

Please advise! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting version to an empty one? 

version: ''

Comment: Yes I tried that too. But I didn't manage to find the structure of the behat.yml file, seems like there are lots of parameters available.

Answer (score 2):

This is the configuration that work for me. Requirements are:

- Appium server should be started. I use the desktop version.
- Also you need and avd emulated device. Create one using Android dev tools(give a nice name, you will need that name to be added to behat config).
- add this to you behat config file (configuration is called android but you can add this config under you default):

android:

```
   autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/bootstrap/
   extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://google.com
      javascript_session: 'foo' 
      sessions:
       foo:
        appium:
         browser: "chrome"
         appium_host: "http://127.0.0.1"
         appium_port: "4723"
         capabilities: {"platformName": "Android", "deviceName": "Android Emulator", "browser": "chrome", "avd": "Nexus"}   suites: # list of test suites available for current profile ("default" in this case)
    default: # this suite is called "default"
      paths: # check these paths
        features: %paths.base%/Features
        bootstrap: %paths.base%/Android/bootstrap/
      contexts: # use these contexts (test suites)
        - FeatureContextAndroid: # FeatureContext class"
        - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\RawMinkContext
```

In this configuration "foo" is just a name you can use whatever name you want. Appium port/ host are the default one.   I use chrome to run  my test. Also the name of my emulator is "Nexus". The "avd" need to be the exact name that you  have used when the device was created (you can use whatever name you want).

If you want to debug or what to see what are the exact capabilities supported by behat through mink extension for Appium breakpoints the test run in library "AppiumFactory.php" (Vendor\behat\mink-extension\src\behat\MinkExtension\ServiceContainer\Drivers)